# Use multiple files in Ivy makepom Ant target

Tags: ant, ivy

My project has multiple mostly independent modules each with their own Ivy files.  A couple of the modules are 'top-level' in that nothing depends on them, they just depend on other modules.

I'd like to generate a pom for those modules to use to publish the dependencies for my users to consume.

The makepom task only accepts a single file via the `ivyfile` attribute afaict.  I create a master module which declares that it depends on the top-level modules and provide that to makepom, but it does not transitively include the dependencies of the top level modules, it only lists the top level modules themselves.

I realize I could just provide several pom files, but for my sanity, i'd prefer to keep it to just one.

So I am wondering if you can somehow pass multiple Ivy files to the make pom task, or if there is a way to get it to list *all* the dependencies when I use a master Ivy file?  Or at worst, is there an easy way to merge pom files w/o doing it by hand?

Comment: The whole purpose of Ivy (and Maven and Gradle) is not to worry about transitive dependencies. If you have everything configured correctly, your `pom.xml` should only list top level dependencies and nothing else. When Ivy (or Maven) fetches those top level modules, it will pull down those dependencies. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: No, I just wanted to have everything in a single file more as a documentation artifact than anything -- we're distributing it as a txt file at the moment.  The application itself is closed source, so it's not like someone will be able to grab it from Maven Central.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a documentation concern, configure each module to generate a report of it's transitive dependencies, see the ivy [report](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html) task.

The [makepom](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/makepom.html) task only accepts a single argument because just like a Maven project modules only have a single file that declares its dependencies.

Perhaps what you could do is create a parent ivy file which has a dependency on each child module?

Comment: I did try to create a parent ivy file that had dependencies on the children modules and that sort of worked, I got a pom that said it depended on those modules, but no listing of their jars.  I would have had to then makepom each child module.  I realize that'd probably be the maven way to do it, but I don't want to provide 22 poms in the distribution.

Comment: @Michael Your best approach is to generate a dependency report, based on the parent ivy file. That will get all the dependencies. Maven parent POMs rarely give you the full picture. (Maven as equivolent dependency reporting functionality)

Answer (score 0):

As Mark O'Connor pointed out, the `<ivy:report>` task does an excellent job of documenting all the transitive jars. Which ones are required for runtime, compilation, etc.

Another possibility is to use `<ivy:retrieve>` to retrieve all the jars used by your Master module into an empty directory. Even if this isn't required by your project itself. The list of required jars would be a simple directory listing.